# Pushing a local file to a directory in github repo

Tags: git, github

I have a file in my local repo that I want to push to a directory in my Github repo.

I have the following file:

```
F:\Development\Python\Workspace\StringCalculator.py
```

I need to push this file to the following path of my repo:

```
https://github.com/Gouravchawla/PyCodeFiesta/tree/master/GUI
```

**How do I push the file to this location?** I have tried the following commands in Git Shell:

```
$ git remote add newremote https://github.com/Gouravchawla/PyCodeFiesta/tree/master/GUI
$ git push newremote master
```

When I execute the above commands I get the following error:

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Gouravchawla/PyCodeFiesta/tree/master/GUI/' not found
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help and insight in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot push single files to directories inside remote repositories. Git works with full directory snapshots and you can only push commits (history).

So, to get your file into your repository, you have to create a commit containing the file:

```
git clone https://github.com/Gouravchawla/PyCodeFiesta
cd PyCodeFiesta
cp 'F:\Development\Python\Workspace\StringCalculator.py' GUI/
git add GUI/StringCalculator.py
git commit -m 'Added StringCalculator file'
git push origin master:master
```